# AttributeError: operate instance has no attribute 'allow'

Tags: python, attributes, instance

for some reason I keep getting this error: operate instance has no attribute 'allow'

could someone please explain as to how my instance attributes are messing up? I thought I was implementing them correctly.

Comment: it's `__init__` not `_init_`

Answer (score 1):

You never initialized `self.allow`. The constructor method is called `__init__`, not `_init_`. So:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.allow=True
```

Instead of:

```
def _init_(self):
    self.allow=True
```

So it's clear, only `__init__` gets called automatically upon instantiation. Your `_init_` method was simply never called. Furthermore, this naming convention (`__`) is true for all magic methods; in other words, they all have to begin and end with *double* underscores.